# Can an interrupt function call a regular function?

Tags: interrupt

If I want to create an interrupt and have it do something, can this 'something' be written in a regular function that I also use outside of the interrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you may.

Yet keep the function in question short, you don't want to spend too much time in interruption.

Another way is to set up a variable state in the interruption, and call the function in question in the normal cycle when the variable is in the desired state.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You just have to make sure your function is [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).
If it accesses no memory beyond its parameters and (non `static`) local
variables, you should be fine. If it accesses global variables, hardware
registers, or `static` locals, it is unlikely to be, and only detailed
analysis will tell you for sure.

Beware also of the library functions you call: some of them are not
themselves reentrant and should therefore be avoided. See for example
[the manual of `strtok()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga6ace85338eafe22a0ff52c00eb9779b8), which explicitly addresses the
reentrancy problem.

Comment: In addition, if the function is only called by the one ISR, _and_ it will always run to completion (won't be interrupted and run another time before the previous call finishes), it doesn't need to be re-entrant.

Comment: @JRobert: The OP stated that the function would also be called from non-interrupt context. That other call would need to be inside a critical section if one wanted to ensure the function is never called while another call has not finished.

Comment: True enough, making my comment irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but it will increase the complexity of your program.
Often when entering an interrupt service routine, the first thing you do is disabling interrupts - the make sure the callback completes reliably. 
This is something you will have to consider if you want to use the same routine for a 'regular' scenario

Comment: You wrote: “_the first thing you do is disabling interrupts_”: on AVRs at least, you don't. The hardware does it right before executing the interrupt vector.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to create an interrupt and have it do something, can this 'something' be written in a regular function that I also use outside of the interrupt?

The right answer is yes and no.

The issue here is reentrancy : whether a function can be interrupted while it's being called by another. Not all functions are re entrant so the safer assumption is that they are.

Another issue with calling a function from within the isr is overhead.

The typical solutions are:

1. Make sure that the function called from the isr is re entrant.
2. The simplest way to assure that is to a. Limit your calling of that from the isr. Or b. Create two versions of the same function. And call them separately.

Btw, I routinely call functions from within isr. In my case through function pointers.

Comment: You left out ***not*** at the end of  “Not all functions are re entrant so the safer assumption is that they are.”